# Trigonometric equation with hyperbolic functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I have to show that the following equations has exactly two solutions provided that $\frac{y}{k} \ge \sinh p_0$ where $p_0$ is the (positive) solution to $p \tanh p = 1$
$$y = x \cosh(k/x), x \gt 0 \\
y = M, M \in \mathbb{R}$$

Plotting the graph of $y$ against $x$ I have found that the graph of this function looks like a parabola with a minimum. So I thought I could somehow compute this minimum point.
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \cosh{\frac{k}{x}} - k \frac{\sinh{\frac{k}{x}}}{x} = 0$$

However, I am not really sure on how to continue.

Comment: The problem is not well defined, I guess it should be $x > 0$ otherwise you have a problem. Also I don't understand the problem. This does not makes sense since you're basically defining a function so what does it mean to look for "solution"?

Comment: @Plussoyeur sorry I omitted some details. I have edited my questions to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: Still does not make any sense. A function cannot have two solutions. Do you mean two extrema?

Comment: @Plussoyeur - they are looking for solutions to the equation $M = x\cosh \frac kx$ for a given $M$. There is no problem with $x < 0$, except that it will only provide you with solutions for $M < 0$, and then only $1$.

Comment: I suggest you make the substitution $u = \frac kx$, and solve the problem as if $u$ was what you were looking for. Once you are done, substituting back for $x$ will give you the solution you are after.

Comment: Ok now the problem is well defined with the edition made.